# Diablo III: UEE issue

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4, psn, playstation-plus

Yesterday I started downloading Diablo III: Ultimate Evil Edition from the PSN. 
However I'm facing what I think is a bug: 4 files are being downloaded, two named "normally" (update file and installation file, 20GB) and two with "Italian" (since I live in Italy) word after the normal name (40GB). 
What's the matter? Do I have to download all of the files or having the "Italian" version is good enough to play (even if I'd prefer the english version)?!

EDIT: on the PS4's homescreen I have TWO games, not just only one. I have the "original" one and the "Italian" version...

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a bug here.

There are data files containing the non-localized data (textures, models, sound effects, etc) and there are data files containing the localized data (text, sounds, video, etc).

This is pretty much expected behaviour, and you can't run the game without both the non-localized data and *a* set of localized data (i.e., could be another language if you change the playstation settings).

Comment: Well many people on the web say that you only need the localized version and not the "generic" one. In addition to what I've written before: on the home screen of the PS4 there are TWO Diablo III, not just only one...